# JobTracker is not yet RUNNING - Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am on a lab with 20 nodes and I am trying to run my Hadoop program but when I command "hadoop jar" I am always getting an Error `**ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTrackerNotYetInitializedException: JobTracker is not yet RUNNING**`

-I am not a sudo-user.

-I cannot even run the WordCount example.

the jps gives me:

```
23712 JobTracker
25685 Jps
23504 NameNode
```

on the master node. I have searched a lot at Google but I found nothing except from some solutions which didn't solve my problem at all... Please can anyone help me? Ask me any information that you think it may be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `/etc/hosts` file of each of the nodes adding the IP address of each of them and a host name. For example:

```
168.168.255.1 node1
168.168.255.2 node2
```

Once this is done in all the nodes, you may need to restart all the services.

Comment: I have set it this way